# svn ssh user access to single repo

Tags: svn

I'm using svn+ssh to checkout from my repo, now a fellow developer has to get access to a single project within the repo. How can I give him access to a single repo without having to use ssh keys?

Basically I just want to add a new user on the server, and somehow restrict his access to just one repo

Comment: To just one repo or to one single project within the repo?

Comment: And: I guess you want to give him write-access?

Comment: it's restricted access to a single project within the repo

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about svn administration, but what we do in my organisation is we run svnserve and configured svnserve to use an auth and passwd file to [validate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth.general) access to repositories.